# Dot product in LookAt Matrix implementation

Tags: opengl, matrix, linear-algebra, glm-math

I was going through an implementation of lookAt matrix for creating view matrix in OpenGL. This particular implementation is from glm math library.

When calculating the lookAt matrix the position vector of the transform is calculated as the dot product of respective orientation axis with the eye position. For example the x value of the position vector is `-dotProduct(RightVector, eyeVector)`

I know that dot product value indicates how similar two vectors are with each other. But why is it used here to calculate position?

This function describes lookAt matrix for right handed coordinates system:

```
 GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> lookAtRH(vec<3, T, Q> const& eye, vec<3, T, Q> const& center, vec<3, T, Q> const& up)
{
    vec<3, T, Q> const f(normalize(center - eye));
    vec<3, T, Q> const s(normalize(cross(f, up)));
    vec<3, T, Q> const u(cross(s, f));

    mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(1);
    Result[0][0] = s.x;
    Result[1][0] = s.y;
    Result[2][0] = s.z;
    Result[0][1] = u.x;
    Result[1][1] = u.y;
    Result[2][1] = u.z;
    Result[0][2] =-f.x;
    Result[1][2] =-f.y;
    Result[2][2] =-f.z;
    Result[3][0] =-dot(s, eye);
    Result[3][1] =-dot(u, eye);
    Result[3][2] = dot(f, eye);
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to "lookAt" define the position and orientation of the camera (eye) in the world. A matrix which is set by this parameters would transform form view space to world space. It can take coordinates which are relative to the camera and transform them to coordinates in the world.

But the view matrix has to transform from world space to view space. The view matrix has to take coordinates in the world and to calculate the corresponding coordinate relative to the camera.
The matrix which transforms from world space to view space is the [inverse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) of that matrix which defines the camera position and orientation in the world.

Think about this algorithm as the optimized computation of the inverse camera matrix.
The input is the position of the camera in world space. It has to be calculate the position of the camera in relation to the orientation of the camera. For that the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is used. The dot product can "project" a vector to an other vector. It calculates the component (length) of vector along an other vector or axis. Note, `s`, `u` and `f` are [Unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector). In this case the dot product is used to calculate the `x`, `y` and `z` component of `eye` in relation to the axis `s`, `u` and `-f`. `s`, `u` and `-f` are the axis of the world space as seen from view space.
This is exactly the same as transforming a vector by the upper left 3x3 of the view matrix.

Comment: I know generally how view matrices work in OpenGL. What I'm interested in is as to why dot product is used to calculate the position of the eye in this inverse lookAt matrix.

Comment: @LennyWhite Your question is a bit unclear to me. Do you want to know what the dot product does,, in general? Anyway, I've extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks this helped a bit. But would using dot product like this, also be equivalent to multiplying a rotational lookAt matrix (left 3x3 of the matrix) with translational eye matrix in order `R * T`?

Comment: @LennyWhite If `T` is a (4x4) translation matrix about `eye` and `R` is a (4x4) rotation matrix which contains the upper left 3x3 of the view matrix, then `V = R * T` where  `V` is the view matrix.

Comment: Yes I know. Anyway I think `This is exactly the same as transforming a vector by the upper left 3x3 of the view matrix` more or less answers my question.